# How to fix 404 error after executing local server using python

Tags: python, html, json, d3.js

I am setting up my local server using python command "python -m http.server 8888 &." I am using the exact directory location where my files reside but still it is showing 404 file not found or location does not exist. Can someone please help me as I have tried every possible way to solve this issue. I have also installed uniform server and I have turned it off before executing the commands. Is there any issue because of installing Uniform server? Below is my code and the error associated with it.

Edit1: I was using flask but this is a normal local server code just the folder name is flask.[The image is showing location of the folder where my files reside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYqvw.png)

```
C:\Users\OneDrive\Documents\flask_app

C:\Users\OneDrive\Documents\flask_app>python -m http.server 8888 &.
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8888 (http://0.0.0.0:8888/) ...

http://localhost:8888/visualization.js

Output:
Error response
Error code: 404

Message: File not found.

Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND - Nothing matches the given URI.
```

Comment: Please provide some of your Flask code, it seems as if your app.route is not pointing to any existing file.

Comment: What u get on http://0.0.0.0:8888/